# Why does Dispose not seem to work when called from VB6?

Tags: c#, com

I have a C# program which is COM visible.

I do:

```
public class Image
{
    private float height;

    public void Init(string path) {
        using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path)) {
            height = image.PhysicalDimension.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

... and the image is correctly disposed when Init is called from VB6, as you'd expect.

But when the following is used, and Dispose *is* called from VB6, the image pointed to by the path is NOT released even though Dispose() is called:

```
public class Image
{
    private bool disposed = false;
    System.Drawing.Image image = null;

    public void Init(string path) {
        if (null != image) {
            image.Dispose();
            image = null;
        }
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
    }

    ~Image() {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposed) return;
        if (null != image) {
            image.Dispose();
            image = null;
        }
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Why does calling Dispose from a VB6 binary on a C# class not seem to work but the using statement works?

Note: I'm certain that VB6 is calling Dispose(). It's not conditional, and logging proves in the actual code that we execute statements following the Dispose() call.

Comment: It is certainly very wrong code, the ~Image() finalizer is lethal.  But no explanation why calling Dispose() from the vb6 program could not work.  Logging is not a great way to debug code, there's that.   And we know that we are not looking at the real code.  Use the debugger, ask a question if you don't know how.

Comment: Why is the Image finalizer lethal?

Comment: May it be that you call `Init()` and `Dispose()` more than once? Note that `disposed` is set once you call `Dispose()` for the first time.

Comment: No, Init and Dispose are called only once. Of this I'm very certain.